# Where can I find the "Technology Adapters" from Oracle?

Tags: ejb, weblogic, adapter, jca

I want to use the file adapter from Oracle® Fusion Middleware to access file system in a recommended way.  I can find the document of the adapter from http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/integration.1111/e10231/intro.htm.  The document only mentions the adapters are part of Oracle® Fusion Middleware, but never mention which specific product includes the adapters.  I downloaded and installed Weblogic Server and JDeveloper, but they seems not include the adapters.

Could anyone give me some suggestions?  Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are part of [Oracle Integration Adapters](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/adapters/overview/index.html).

The download link is at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/soasuite/downloads/index.html

See the "**Prerequisites & Recommended Install Process**"

No #9 of the "Recommended Components"

Comment: Thanks JoseK, it is exactly in the SOA suite.

Answer (score 0):

If im not mistaken this is a list of said adapters, 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12524_01/doc.1013/e14481/adapters.htm
not sure if thats of any help, try looking up one of the ones listed.

Comment: Hi Jacxel, I saw that page but after installing my Fusion Middleware, I can not find the adapters.  It should be in (FusionMiddleware Dir)/soa/connectors/ directory, as mentioned in this blog post:

http://technology.amis.nl/2012/01/22/using-the-oracle-weblogic-technology-adapters-with-custom-java-message-driven-bean-mdb-triggered-by-file-adapter-part-of-the-story/

But the soa dirctory is not found after the installation...